# self.name = name in Swift . I don't understand why this codes are needed

Tags: swift, init

```
class person {
    var name : String 

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name 
    }
}
```

I am learning Swift class chapter

I don't understand why `init(name:String) self.name = name`  code is needed 
what the purpose of this code is.

I declared `var name: String` 
and again `init(name: String)`, why is `self.name = name` needed?

what's different between just `var name` and `self.name = name`?

Comment: `var name: String` declares your property.  The initializer `init` is called when you create an instance of the class.  The string passed into `person(name: "jihoon")` will be assigned to the property.  In the statement `self.name = name`, `self.name` refers to the property and `name` is the string passed in - "jihoon" in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Classes` and `structures` must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.

```
class person {
    var name : String // undetrmined state
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
class person2 {
    var name : String = "default value" // detrmined state
    // Now these intializer are not optional. You can use these initializer or not.
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    init() {
    }
}
// Aother example for optional stored property
class person3 {
    var name : String?  // detrmined state, because default value for optional is nil
    // Now these intializer are not optional. You can use these initializer or not.
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    init() {
    }
}
```

For more info read this one [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: Hi jihoon, did you check my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your help ! yes i have checked :)

Answer (score 3):

Look into something called *variable scope*. In your code - there are two "name variables - a class (or instance) variable and a "parameter in your `init`.

The latter - `init(name:)` only is in use **within** your initialization function, meaning the instance has *no* name without the `self.name = name` once you've created the instance.

The former is available - to the instance -  as long as your instance of the class `person` is.

To explain further, try this. Change your code to be:

```
class Person {
    var myName : String
    var myOtherName : String 

    init(name: String) {
        self.myName = name
    }
}
```

In your app or view controller, do this:

```
let myPerson = Person(name: "john")
print(myPerson.myName)       // prints "jihoon"
print(myPerson.myOtherName)  // prints nothing
print(myPerson.name)         // generates a build error because name doesn't exist
```

One last note - in Swift class names are capitalized, so the best name is `Person`, not `person`.